# How do I programmatically set a django choice field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a choice field, and I want to set it during the saving of a form in django.

I want the users choices to generate additional model updates - and one model I want to update has a choice field.  I know the value I want that choice field to be, but when I create a new model object, How do I set the choice field in code?

For example -

Say I want to create a new Auto object and I infer if the auto is one of a choice of Luxury, Economy or Standard.

I want to set the value of that choice field in code, before I save the model object...

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

You need to set the choices attribute on the field. You can generate these choices dynamically as well when your form is getting instantiated like so:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field_name_in_question'].choices = generate_choices_as_tuple()
```

`generate_choices_as_tuple()` will be a function that will return a tuple in the format laid out in the documentation.